# How to detect from inside iOS keyboard the UITextInput settings

Tags: ios, keyboard, uitextfield, custom-keyboard, uitextinput

I would like to customize the iOS keyboard behavior to adapt to the `UITextInput` inside the app that it's showing up.

For example, when someone entering a URL inside Safari, the keyboard's return key should instead say "Go", autocorrect and auto-capitalization should both be spelled.

I looked through `UITextInput` protocol [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInput_Protocol/), but was unable to find any information about detecting the settings. Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should look at [UITextInputTraits](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006896-CH1-SW7), and UITextField supports it.

Comment: Ah this is very helpful - I'll look into it and maybe update the question and/or answer. Thanks!